# SciKit SGD Regressor RBF Kernel Approximation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn and would like to run SVR with RBF kernel. My dataset was quite large so from reading other posts, I was advised to use SGD regression and RBF approximation. Interestingly I get worse results from using SGD with RBF compared to just SGD by itself. I'd imagine this would be due to wrong parameter values. I tried looping through gamma and n_components for RBF sampler and tried a number of parameters for SGD regessor to no avail. I also output the training and cross validation error, and both are roughly the same, so I believe its a bias issue.

Comment: Stackoverflow wont be the best place to ask Machine Learning Domain specific question. I think the better alternative is: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=scikit

Comment: Which approximation are you using? I found Nystroem to work better than the RBFSampler for the same number of dimensions. Also, more dimensions are always better. You should just search gamma and the SGD parameters. Maybe rather try LinearSVC(dual=False) and search C (and gamma).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think the RBF feature space must have a higher accuracy than the linear one? While it is often the case, there is no reason to believe that is must be true. There are whole classes of real world data for which the RBF kernel does poorly

Besides that, there are numerous other questions that could be asked / explored. Such questions are usually not awnserable without someone else using / exploring your data. Such as:

- Are the original feature values normalized correctly?
- Is the approximation method being used appropriate for the amount of data / type of data
- Is the problem ill conditioned or nearly ill conditioned? If so - is our approximation onto of approximation the cause of our errors?
- Are the original features meaningful enough to use RBF for?
- Were the parameter values tested appropriate for my data and its scaling?
- What are the current obtained error rates? What is a reasonable expectation for an ache viable error rate?